# error with spring template parsing

Tags: spring

I started from new Spring Boot project included Web, Devtools, JPA and Mustache modules.

I have simple controller:

```
package com.example.elephant;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("name", "Spring");
        System.out.println("11111111111111111111");
        return new ModelAndView("index",model);
    }
}
```

and simple template /resources/templates/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{name}}
</body>
</html>
```

application class:

```
package com.example.elephant;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ElephantApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ElephantApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application log:

```
2018-04-24 15:09:11.333  INFO 7402 --- [  restartedMain] c.example.elephant.ElephantApplication   : Started ElephantApplication in 5.906 seconds (JVM running for 6.477)
2018-04-24 15:09:29.231  INFO 7402 --- [nio-8036-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-04-24 15:09:29.232  INFO 7402 --- [nio-8036-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-04-24 15:09:29.252  INFO 7402 --- [nio-8036-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
11111111111111111111
```

All ok, but I have 404 error. It seems I have a problem with template parsing but I can't understand why.

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Apr 24 15:09:29 MSK 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rename your template file to:

```
index.mustache
```

The file ending has changed with Spring Boot 2 from html to mustache:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8997